# R - survdiff() output fields

Tags: r, survival-analysis

The question is about the output structure of survdiff() function form the 'survival' library. Namely, I have a data frame containing survival data

```
> dat
         ID      Time Treatment Gender Censored
    1  E002 2.7597536       IND      F        0
    2  E003 4.2710472   Control      M        0
    3  E005 1.4784394       IND      F        0
    4  E006 6.8993840   Control      F        1
    5  E008 9.5934292       IND      M        0
    6  E009 2.9897331   Control      F        0
    7  E014 1.3470226       IND      F        1
    8  E016 2.1683778   Control      F        1
    9  E018 2.7597536       IND      F        1
    10 E022 1.3798768       IND      F        0
    11 E023 0.7227926       IND      M        1
    12 E024 5.5195072       IND      F        0
    13 E025 2.4640657   Control      F        0
    14 E028 7.4579055   Control      M        1
    15 E029 5.5195072   Control      F        1
    16 E030 2.7926078       IND      M        0
    17 E031 4.9938398   Control      F        0
    18 E032 2.7268994       IND      M        0
    19 E033 0.1642710       IND      M        1
    20 E034 4.1396304   Control      F        0
```

and a model

```
> diff = survdiff(Surv(Time, Censored) ~ Treatment+Gender, data = dat)
> diff
Call:
survdiff(formula = Surv(Time, Censored) ~ Treatment + Gender, 
    data = dat)

                            N Observed Expected (O-E)^2/E (O-E)^2/V
Treatment=Control, Gender=M 2        1     1.65  0.255876  0.360905
Treatment=Control, Gender=F 7        3     2.72  0.027970  0.046119
Treatment=IND, Gender=M     5        2     2.03  0.000365  0.000519
Treatment=IND, Gender=F     6        2     1.60  0.100494  0.139041

 Chisq= 0.5  on 3 degrees of freedom, p= 0.924
```

I'm wondering what's the field of the output object that contains the values from the very right column (O-E)^2/V? I'd like to use them further but can't obtain them neither from diff$obs, diff$exp, diff$var nor from their combinations.

Your help's gonna be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can find that out in a simple way. When you just run the line "diff", you actually invoke `print.survdiff(diff)`. You can download the package source for the survival package [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/index.html), then open the archive file and in the R folder you will find a file containing this function, print.survdiff.S (you can open it with Notepad++ / Sublime / anything that can read R syntax).

As far as I can see, the last column comes from the line

```
((otmp-etmp)^2)/ diag(x$var)
```

And `otmp` and `etmp` are obtained form the object with

```
if (is.matrix(x$obs)){
    otmp <- apply(x$obs,1,sum)
    etmp <- apply(x$exp,1,sum)
    }
else {
    otmp <- x$obs
    etmp <- x$exp
    }
```

So you could obtain the same by running this code with `diff` instead of `x` (although I would advise you not to call your object diff, as that is a base function in R).